# QGraphicPixmapItem double click event does not go to parent widget while QGraphicsTextItem send

Tags: qt, double-click, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicstextitem, qgraphicspixmapitem

I have a main widget in Qt and this widget contains a `QGraphicsView` and inside it `QGraphicsScene`. In scene I add `QGraphicsPixmapItem`s and `QGraphicsTextItem`s. In main widget I handle `QWidget::mouseDoubleClickEvent ( QMouseEvent * event )`, my items are all set flags with:

```
mItem->setFlag ( QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable );
mItem->setFlag ( QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable );
mItem->setFlag ( QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable);
```

Because I want to move items in scene and select them and also I want when double click occurs main widget handles that. When I double click onto `QGraphicsTextItem` it enters to `mouseDoubleClickEvent` in main widget, however when I double click to `QGraphicsPixmap` item, it absorbs double click and does not send it to main widget. Also when `ItemIsFocusable` flag is not set, `QGraphicsTextItem` also does absorb the double click event. Why does it occur?.
I did not want to implement subclass of `QGraphicsItem`s and wanted to use already defined methods. Here is a picture of what I do:

[image]

Comment: A textual description of what you think your code is doing may be rather different from what it actually does. I suggest posting an example of your code in order to improve the question.

Comment: What do you expect the `QGraphicsPixmapItem` to do on double click ? Items do their default implementation: Unless you subclass them and do your own implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for this because my `QGraphicsPixmapItem` and `QGraphicsTextItem` behaves differently on double clicking: `QGraphicsTextItem` sends its double click event to parent while `QGraphicsPixmapItem` does not, I commented out the `ItemIsFocusable` property :

```
mItem->setFlag ( QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable );
mItem->setFlag ( QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable );
//mItem->setFlag ( QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable);
```

Because even if `ItemIsFocusable` is a `QGraphicsItem` property, it does not behave same in different `QGraphicsItem` inherited classes,
so for handling double click I installed an event filter on `QGraphicsScene` that contains `QGraphicsItem`s in main widget.

```
this->ui.graphicsViewMainScreen->scene ( )->installEventFilter ( this );
```

And as implementation of event filter :

```
bool MyMainWidget::eventFilter ( QObject *target , QEvent *event )
{
    if ( target == this->ui.graphicsViewMainScreen->scene ( ) )
    {
        if ( event->type ( ) == QEvent::GraphicsSceneMouseDoubleClick )
        {
            QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *mouseEvent = static_cast<QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *>( event );
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now I can detect double clicks on `QGraphicsItem`s on my main widget's scene.